# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: и, пунктуация, синтаксис

Является ли слово "вдали" общим второстепенным членом в сложносочинённом предложении?

> Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями
> мельница, и всё ещё она похожа на
> маленького человечка, размахивающего
> руками.

От этого зависит постановка запятой перед союзом "и".
Заранее благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, здесь нет общего второстепенного члена, запятая нужна. Т.к. здесь нельзя от обоих сказуемых задать один и тот же вопрос. Запятая здесь стоит перед союзом и, поскольку он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части  - ***мельница***.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Ваши ответы на все мои вопросы. И в дальнейшем я надеюсь на Вашу помощь.
Лара.

Comment: Обращайтесь. Участники форума вам всегда помогут.